# Unable to retrieve single entity

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, wcf-ria-services, domainservices

I'm trying to retrieve a single entity by its ID in the `DomainService`.

However the type of that entity is not generated in the client.
Here is my query:

```
public Contact GetContact(int contactId)
{
  return DbContext.Contacts
    .Include(c => c.Phones)
    .Include(c => c.Addresses)
    .SingleOrDefault(c => c.ContactId == contactId);
}
```

The `Phone` entity isn't generated on the client.

I tried decorating this method with `[Query]`, but then I get the following compile-time exception:

> Query operation 'GetContact' cannot be marked composable since its return type 'Models.Contact' does not implement IEnumerable of T.

Is there any way to create a WCF RIA query that returns a single entity by ID?

Comment: You are missing an `[Include]` attribute in the Models.Contact for Phone or Addresses.

Comment: @Rikkos, nope, it's there. Besides, it looks that what bother him is that it doesn't return `IEnumerable<T>`, after we solve that I believe the `Phone` and `Address` entities will be generated at the client as well.

Comment: so without the `[Query]` attribute, it does compile, but your `Phone` and `Address` entities aren't being generated, even though they exist in your `DbContext` as `DbSet`

Comment: can you add this attribute `[Query(IsComposable = false)]`

Comment: @Rikkos, alight, i tried `IsComposable=false` and now it compiles. but the Phone and Address entities are still not generated at client (it's marked as `Include` in the `Contact` entity)

Comment: What about `DbSet<Phone>` and `DbSet<Address>` in your `DbContext` class. Thats all I can think of.

Comment: Please post your idea of `IsComposable` as answer, anyways the phone and address is not generated, but the `IsComposable=false` answers the question however.

Comment: Will do, I was thinking the other day but it might not work, if you have your Phone.cs you can rename him to Phone.Shared.cs this will force the WCF code generator to transfer the Phone to the wcf ria project, but the problem might be that it will not be generated as entity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the `IsComposable` property will allow it to build. But as in our discussion, I don't know why your `Phone` and `Address` entities are not being generated.

```
[Query(IsComposable=false)]
public Contact GetContact(int contactId)
{
  return DbContext.Contacts
    .Include(c => c.Phones)
    .Include(c => c.Addresses)
    .SingleOrDefault(c => c.ContactId == contactId);
}
```

Comment: Any ideas why the `Phone` and `Address` entities are not generated in the client? The `ICollection<Phone> Phones` property in the `Contact` entity is decorated with the [`Include`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.domainservices.server.includeattribute.aspx) attribute, same applies to the `Addresses` property.

Answer (score 1):

RIA Service methods require an `IQueryable<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>` to work. It works with change sets, not single elements.

Change it to this (and stop trying to return a single object):

```
public IQueryable<Contact> GetContact(int contactId)
{
  return DbContext.Contacts
    .Include(c => c.Phones)
    .Include(c => c.Addresses)
    .Where(c => c.ContactId == contactId);
}
```

Simply apply your FirstOrDefault() to the client side code (once the data is loaded of course).

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a way to return single entities, take a look at [my discussion with Rikkos](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10966778/unable-to-retrieve-single-entity#comment14335634_10966778) Who revealed that there is a way to expose a single entity. The problem remains the included entities who are not exposed.

Comment: @Shimmy: Every example I have found indicates that even if you find a way to fool the compiler, there is no suitable client-side code-template for generating the WCF code needed to return a single object (rather than a table). Unless they stuck something new in Silverlight 5 this is just like using Entity Framework (i.e. all set based).

Comment: OK. I tried returning a collection, but the `Phone` and `Address` entities are not generated. Is it because there isn't a Phone queryable? What if I don't want to expose all the phones, I want them to be returned only per contact/customer?

Comment: @Shimmy: Will need to post more code to figure out any remaining issues. Yo may be missing attributes, or the classes are protected/private/internal... or one of a number of other potential problems.

Answer (score 0):

RIA-enabled controls like DomainDataSource and DataPager use LINQ 'Take()' with just about every single load operation they generate (check your Fiddler trace to see what I mean). I haven't watched for long enough to say its 100% of the time, but its most of the time. These controls expect an IQueryable, and will barf at random otherwise when you try and do things like sorting, pagination, grouping, etc. It's really not that big a deal to call .FirstOrDefault().